# Is the arrow between two $0$ arrows $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose given exact sequences of abelian groups $0\to A_0\to A_1\to A_2\to A_3\to 0$ and $0\to A_0'\to A'_1\to A'_2\to A_3'\to 0$ and $f_i\colon A_i\to A_i'$. Suppose $f_1=f_3=0$, is it true that $f_2=0$? If not, is it true if we assume $f_0=0$ or $f_0$ is isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple counterexample, where $f_0$ is both $0$ and an isomorphism.  Let $A_0=A_0'=A_1=A_3'=0$, $A_2=A_3=G$, and $A_1'=A_2'=H$ for some abelian groups $G$ and $H$.  Then $f_2$ can be any homomorphism $G\to H$ at all and the diagram will still commute.